# Proof regarding powersets and subsets

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove the following implication : 
$\mathcal{P}$ ( *A* ) ⊂ $\mathcal{P}$ ( *B* ) → *A* ⊂ *B*

Solution : First off, we know that *A* ⊂ $\mathcal{P}$ ( *A* ). From the definition of subset, it follows that..

*x* ∈ *A* → x ∈ $\mathcal{P}$ ( *A* )

Because $\mathcal{P}$ ( *A* ) ⊂ $\mathcal{P}$ ( *B* ), we can show that

*x* ∈ $\mathcal{P}$ ( *A* ) → *x* ∈ $\mathcal{P}$ ( *B* ).  This shows that *A* ⊂ $\mathcal{P}$ ( *B* ). I'm pretty sure we can infer the implication from this result, both *A* and *B* are subsets of the same thing, but I'm unsure how to take the next step from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is not correct, since $A\not\subset\mathcal P(A)$. What we have is $A\in\mathcal P(A)$ instead.

You can prove your statement as follows: suppose that $A\not\subset B$. Then there is some $a\in A$ such that $a\notin B$. Therefore $\{a\}\in\mathcal P(a)\setminus\mathcal P(B)$ and so $\mathcal P(A)\not\subset\mathcal P(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

For a cleaner solution:

Suppose $A\not\subseteq B$.  This means that there is some $x\in A$ such that $x\notin B$.

It follows then that $\{x\}\in\mathcal{P}(A)$ and that $\{x\}\notin \mathcal{P}(B)$ implying that $\mathcal{P}(A)\not\subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$.

This in turn implies what we originally wanted to show by contrapositive.

---

For a direct proof: (*corrected, thanks to @palmpo*)

Suppose that $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$.

Further, suppose that $x\in A$.  We have then $\{x\}\in \mathcal{P}(A)$.  As $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$ we have then $\{x\}\in\mathcal{P}(B)$.  It follows then that $x\in B$, thus proving that $A\subseteq B$.

---

Note: the elements in $\mathcal{P}(A)$ are *subsets* of $A$, not elements of $A$.  You had written $x\in A\implies x\in \mathcal{P}(A)$ which is incorrect.

Comment: For the direct proof, I think you meant: Let $x\in A$, then $\{x\}\in\mathcal P(A)$. Since $\mathcal P(A)\subseteq\mathcal P(B)$, $\{x\}\in\mathcal P(B)$. This implies $\{x\}\subseteq B$ so $x\in B$.

Comment: @palmpo I apologize, I spoke too soon.  You are correct.  Somehow, I went and proved my assumption... I must be tired.